# Stack imbalance while using RcppParallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp, random, armadillo

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppArmadillo;
using namespace RcppParallel;
using namespace std;

struct Sum : public Worker
{   
  vector<string> output;

  Sum() {}
  Sum(const Sum& sum, Split) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    vector<string> states;
    states.push_back("a");
    states.push_back("b");
    states.push_back("c");
    states.push_back("d");

    vector<double> probs;
    probs.push_back(0.3);
    probs.push_back(0.4);
    probs.push_back(0.1);
    probs.push_back(0.2);

    vector<string> rstat = sample(states, 1, false, wrap(probs));
    output.push_back(rstat[0]);

  }

  void join(const Sum& rhs) { 
    for(int i=0;i<rhs.output.size();i++) {
      output.push_back(rhs.output[i]);
    }
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector parallelVectorSum(int n) {

  Sum sum;

  parallelReduce(0, n, sum);

  return wrap(sum.output);
}
```

The above code is just an experiment to learn `RcppParllel`. I did a lot of search and found that we should avoid the use of data type such as `CharacterVector`, `NumericVector`, etc. That is why I have used `C++ STL`.

**Output 1**

```
> parallelVectorSum(1)
[1] "b"
```

**Output 2**

```
> parallelVectorSum(11)
 [1] "d" "a" "b" "b" "d" "a" "b" "b" "d" "b" "a"
```

**Output 3**

```
> parallelVectorSum(111)
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 7 then 6
  [1] "a" "b" "d" "b" "a" "b" "d" "d" "a" "b" "a" "b" "d" "b" "b" "c" "a" "a" "a" "d" "b" "b" "b" "a" "c" "a" "b" "a"
 [29] "a" "b" "b" "d" "a" "b" "c" "b" "b" "d" "d" "b" "b" "a" "b" "a" "d" "b" "b" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "a" "a" "b" "d"
 [57] "a" "a" "b" "d" "a" "a" "c" "d" "b" "c" "a" "d" "a" "d" "d" "b" "a" "a" "d" "b" "b" "d" "d" "b" "b" "b" "a" "a"
 [85] "c" "a" "b" "d" "c" "b" "b" "a" "d" "d" "b" "b" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "c" "b" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "d"
```

In the last run I got a warning related to stack imbalance and I am sure this is because of the use of `sample` function of `RcppArmadillo`. In the definition of `sample` method I found that `R` data type are being used. Infact fourth parameter of `sample` is itself `NumericVector` which is a problem.

What can be the solution of this problem? Do I need to implement my own `sample` function (I don't think it's easy to do - I am a beginner).
Any solution will be appreciated. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already ported the code over from [`RcppArmadillo`'s sample.h](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/da0875587a2388b9a3777ba2edd17b9d943c10d0/inst/include/RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h) to use only `arma::vec`.

See: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/pull/101

The only issue is this will not work with `std::string` as `arma` has no type defined for that. (I suppose you could write it using a `template`?

Comment: Nice. Should we PR that change for `sample()` back into RcppArmadillo?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel need to probably setup a `template` then a PR is good. Also, dependency issues?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel to. I'm probably going to tackle this over the weekend.

Comment: Come to think about it ... this may even fit into Armadillo upstream.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel licensing restrictions though?